# Deployed app in sp2013 opens without any css

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

I just deployed my first basic default app in SP2013 after configuring the app domain for it. But when I tried to open its link,it just opens the page without any css. Its like opening google.com without any css - only text is displayed. Is this normal? If not please advise

It is a sharepoint hosted app running on my VM which has SP2013SP1, Sql2008r2SP1 and VS2012 Ultimate. I tried another basic app , but it also had the same effect. I thought this could be becuase the app domain was not in trusted sites in IE and added the same, still no use.

Comment: What kind of app is it? Is it Provider Hosted or SharePoint Hosted app?

Answer (score 0):

The SharePoint app will loads default CSS using handler and if you inspect view source you should get something like this "/_layouts/15/defaultcss.ashx?ctag=0".
And on the app page Default.aspx, you should have the following 4 ASP.NET directives,

```
<%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" Language="C#" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

This should bring up the top Nav witha link back to your Site Collection and SP logo.

Comment: I am able to see /_layouts/15/defaultcss.ashx?ctag=0 But I am not able to see the other 4 asp.net directives you mentioned.I am stuck at this for two days and is driving me crazy.

Comment: When you create a SharePoint self hosted app using visual studio, it will creates Default.aspx page with all the  above directives. and when you just publish this app, you will see SP logo and "Welcome username" under the logo.

Comment: I created a webapp,created a team sitecollection under it.Created a developer site for app under the webapp. Then I created a sharepoint hosted app by choosing the App for Sharepoint 2013 template, compiled  and deployed it without any code change. After it deployed, it opened the browser and asked it i trusted the app, I said yes, when it opened, the entire page is without any css, no sharpeoint blue bar on top like skydrive,etc. It is just plain text. Pls help.Also, in the manifest.xml, under permission, i changed the scope to sitecollection and gave it full control permission.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar case and for me, the solution was, to create a root site collection (`/`) on the same web application that I was deploying my app, after this the app stated working normally, with all CSS and JS and all show as it should.

This might be related to the SharePoint Hosted apps using some files/resources from this root site collection.